# Why dose the tiny performance boost happen when I reuse the Linq query variable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

**environment:**
SQL CE
Windows Phone 7.5 and above
Visual Studio 2012 update 3
Sample：30 all tasks, 10 today tasks, 10 tomorrow tasks, 10 overdue tasks

**requirements**:
a to do app, and need to show 3 numbers in the homepage, all tasks,today tasks, tomorrow tasks.

**original code:**

```
private Stopwatch sw=new Stopwatch();
using (TasksDataContext db = new TasksDataContext(TasksDataContext.DBConnectionString))
{
     sw.Start();
     var allTask = db.TasksItems.Where(t => t.Title != null && t.IsCompleted != true);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "allTask:"+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     Taskamount = allTask.Count();

     var todayTask = db.TasksItems.Where(t => t.DueDate != null & t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date & t.IsCompleted == false);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("todayTask:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     todayNumber = todayTask.Count();

     var tomorrowTask = db.TasksItems.Where(t => t.DueDate != null & t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1) & t.IsCompleted == false);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tomorrowTask:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     sw.Stop();
     tomorrowNumber = tomorrowTask.Count();
}
```

**lates code:**

```
private Stopwatch sw=new Stopwatch();
using (TasksDataContext db = new TasksDataContext(TasksDataContext.DBConnectionString))
{
     sw.Start();
     var allTask = db.TasksItems.Where(t => t.Title != null && t.IsCompleted != true);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "allTask:"+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     Taskamount = allTask.Count();

     var todayTask = allTask.Where(t => t.DueDate != null & t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date & t.IsCompleted == false);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("todayTask:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     todayNumber = todayTask.Count();

     var tomorrowTask = allTask.Where(t => t.DueDate != null & t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1) & t.IsCompleted == false);
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tomorrowTask:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     sw.Stop();
     tomorrowNumber = tomorrowTask.Count();
}
```

**debug output**
**original:**
1st time:
allTask:9
todayTask:165
tomorrowTask:221

2nd time:
allTask:10
todayTask:179
tomorrowTask:233

3rd time:
allTask:14
todayTask:168
tomorrowTask:225

4th time:
allTask:8
todayTask:181
tomorrowTask:236

5th time:
allTask:8
todayTask:166
tomorrowTask:221


**latest:**
1st time:
allTask:9
todayTask:157
tomorrowTask:216

2nd time:
allTask:8
todayTask:163
tomorrowTask:219

3rd time:
allTask:8
todayTask:161
tomorrowTask:216

4th time:
allTask:8
todayTask:164
tomorrowTask:222

5th time:
allTask:9
todayTask:153
tomorrowTask:210

**Why I modify the code**:
Since the today tasks and tomorrow tasks is sub-set of all tasks.
I think a reuse of the linq query variable will boost the performance.
The result shows a tiny boost.

**What confuse me:**
I read the linq section in MSDN, it said:

> In LINQ the execution of the query is distinct from the query itself;
>   in other words you have not retrieved any data just by creating a
>   query variable.

It made me think a question: Why will it be fast a little bit?According to what the MSDN said:The reuse of linq query will not boost the performance but will hurt the performance.

When the compiler runs the following code:

```
var todayTask = allTask.Where(t => t.DueDate != null & t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date & t.IsCompleted == false);
```

It will do 2 manipulations,one is for allTask and one is for todayTask. But when using "db.taskitems.Where()",it only do a single manipulation.

**My Question**
1. Why is it faster? (Is the compiler optimize my code at compile time?)
2. Is there any better way to boost the speed?

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry, i edit the question. I run the app 5 times. Each line represents the result in each run.

Comment: You do the timing before the counts and the last `Count()` is never measured. Also, the predicates are different, the second runs have `t.Title != null`. Do the counts produce the same results in both alternatives?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, I will do a new test by updating the position of Stopwatch.

Comment: OK, but also report the results of the counts.

Answer (score 0):

This speed up may occur due to extra condition in `allTask` query (`t => t.Title != null`). This is not included in `todayTask` and `tomorrowTask`.

To speed it up you may try to use `Count` with predicate and by removing redundant conditions:

```
var allTask = [...];
Taskamount = allTask.Count();
todayNumber = allTask.Count(t => t.DueDate != null && t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date);
tomorrowNumber = allTask.Count(t => t.DueDate != null && t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1));
```

You may also try `GroupBy`:

```
var result = allTask.GroupBy(x => 1, x => x, (key, g) => new
{
    All = g.Count(),
    Today = g.Count(t => t.DueDate != null && t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date),
    Tomorrow = g.Count(t => t.DueDate != null && t.DueDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1))
}).Single();
```

This should do one query for all agregates, but I don't know if it is supported by all linq drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the new methods. I will check it later.